# Script not running on terminal startup

Tags: bash

I am currently trying to execute a script on CentOS.That runs every time a terminal is opened by any user. I tried placing the script in `/etc/profile.d` and editing `~/.bashrc`. Didn't work properly. It only executes the script for only that particular user (root in my case) and not all users? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try adding it to the users ~/.bash_profile instead of ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 0):

Add your script or command to the end of:

```
/etc/profile
```

That will make it take effect for all users at session open.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you would like to execute new command when terminal was opened.

Follow this step :
In terminal, Edit > Preferences > Tab Title and command > Run a custom command of my shell.

Or
gnome-terminal --tab -e "your command" to open a new tab.

This will make your application run when any user will execute opens up the terminal.